# How can I calculate the percentage difference (increase and decrease) in a the same column? Do I need to use case when?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the percentage difference based on a previous and new value.
However, I want the data to show up in 1 column.
My formula below calculates the percentage increase, but I need to add in the percentage decrease formula as well, which would be

((b.[close] - a.[close])/b.[close])*(100) as '% G/L'

Do I need to do a case when function or is there an easier way?

My current formula is below:

```
    select 
,a.[close] - b.[close] as '$ G/L'
,((a.[close] - b.[close])/b.[close])*(100) as '% G/L'

FROM

   (SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM [Stocks].[dbo].[Live_Ticker_Data]
   WHERE time between  '09:29' and '16:01'

) a INNER JOIN

(SELECT *

FROM Historical_Data
WHERE Date = ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Historical_Data
               WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
                              FROM Historical_Data
                            ))) b

ON a.Ticker = b.Ticker
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Sample data (in a consumable format, **not** an image), and expected results will help us help you

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the gain or loss as a positive value, than add ABS().